# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for a user admin app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

after using stack for idk how many years to get all coding problem related answers, Here I am posting my first question here

I'm building a user admin app with Firebase and Firestore. I have three collections: requests, users, and admins. When a user creates a request in the app, a document is stored in the "requests" collection with fields like ID, request time, reason, and status. I have a listener at the admin end that triggers whenever a new document is created in the "requests" collection with a pending status. My goal is to send admins a notification immediately upon such a document creation.

I've researched and found Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to be a suitable solution. However, I lack cloud infrastructure to set up the Firebase Admin SDK, which is necessary for writing cloud functions to handle these requests from what I've found. Therefore, I'm seeking alternative approaches to achieve notification functionality for new pending requests. Is there any ?

My answer: In my initial approach, I tried creating a background service using Service() with the START_STICKY flag. This service would have continuously monitored the "requests" collection for changes using a Firestore Snapshot listener. The intention was to trigger a notification whenever a new document with a pending status was detected but it didn't seem to work very well.

Comment: It's not recommended to use Firebase Cloud Messaging API on client side. It can work with old version but in latest version it might not even work firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#java